# static local member of static global function?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have a static local variable within a static global function (not class static, global static)...

foo.cpp:

```
static void f()
{
    static T x;
    ...
}
```

Is the x instance guaranteed to be singleton across the application?

What if two translation units defined `static void f()` as above.  Would they each have their own x instance, or would they share?  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` functions have *internal linkage*, so each `f` in each translation unit would be a different independent function, and there would be an instance of `x` per translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the x instance guaranteed to be singleton across the application?

It is guaranteed to be created the first time `f()` is called. It is a `static storage duration object` which means it will be destroyed with the other `static storage duration object` (in the reverse order of creation).

This variable `x` is only visible inside the function `f()`.

> What if two translation units defined static void f() as above. Would they each have their own x instance, or would they share? Why?

Since this is a static function. It is local to the translation unit. Each translation unit that defines this function will have its own copy of both the function and its internal variable. This is not exposed outside the translation unit so it can only be from within the translation unit .